# Reservations : search for available slots with gap in PostgreSql with tsrange

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Reservation table contains reservations tsrange.

```
create table reservation (slot tsrange);
insert into reservation values 
('[2022-02-21 02:00:00,2022-02-21 04:00:00)');
```

I would like to get all available slots for a selected day (2022-02-21 in the example below).
The problem is the 'union all values'.

What I want to have is 2 records

start at 2022-02-21 00:00:00 with 2 hours gap AND
start at 2022-02-21 04:00:00 with 20 hours gap

```
with gaps as (
  select 
    upper(slot) as start, 
    lead(lower(slot),1,upper(slot)) over (ORDER BY slot) - upper(slot) as gap 
  from (
    select * 
    from reservation 
    WHERE lower(slot) >= '2022-02-21'::date 
    AND lower(slot) < '2022-02-22'::date
    union all values 
      ('[2022-02-21 00:00:00, 2022-02-21 08:00:00)'::tsrange), 
      ('[2022-02-21 18:00:00, 2022-02-22 00:00:00)'::tsrange)
  ) as x
) 
select * from gaps where gap > '0'::interval;
```

The result of this query gives one record : Start at 2022-02-21 04:00:00 with 14:00:00 gap

Do not hesitate if you have another query to make a search for availability between two dates

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From PostgreSQL v14 on this is trivial:

```
SELECT TSMULTIRANGE '{[2022-02-21 00:00:00,2022-02-22 00:00:00)}'
       - range_agg(slot)
FROM reservation;
```

Comment: unfortunately i'm using postgresql 10.6

Comment: You didn't say so. With v10, it is time for an upgrade anyway.